# CATransform3D UIScrollView perspective transform on zoom (3D)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, rotation, zooming, catransform3d

I've been attempting to apply a perspective transform to achieve an effect similar to the Apple Maps 3D effect with the added constraint that the transform is applied once a certain zoom scale has been reached rather than clicking a button to enable the feature.

To achieve this I have been doing the following with very buggy results.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scr withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    NSLog(@"Scale: %f", scale);

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    //z distance
    float distance = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

    transform.m34 = - 1.0/distance;

    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, scale * 15 * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        image.layer.transform = transform;
        image.layer.zPosition = distance * ratio;
        image.layer.position = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/3);
    }];

    previousScale = scale;
}
```

What ends up happening is that the perspective transform is applied the first time. However, it also translates the imageview, which is not what I want. Also, subsequent zoom attempts will seemingly continue rotating using the previous rotation as a base (I thought that setting the transform to the identity transform would reset this behavior).

Also, any pointers towards achieving the rotation effect would be much appreciated.

Simply, my question is as follows: How do I properly use the m34 transformation to achieve a transform effect similar to Apple Maps 3D effect.

Bonus Question: Can you point me in the right direction for achieving the rotation effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Able to find the solution? looking for similar solution, could not find... Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a sort of perspective changing the m34 value in the root view is not enough. The topic  is quite complex and it actually requires a special hosting layer the `CATransformLayer`.
Here I've found a [blog article](https://markpospesel.wordpress.com/tag/catransformlayer/) that can help you. Rotation in layer language are applied in the anchor point.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I understand that I should be using a CATransformLayer, however, your answer only addresses why the offset is occurring.